# What is the meaning of come to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Through reading of “LUKÁCS’s Hegel book that had to be published in Switzerland in 1948 because it appeared insufficiently orthodox to his comrades” (ibid.), but also the works of MARX and ENGELS, FETSCHER was prepared for KOJVE’s Hegel interpretation, all the more so that “through contact with Dresden, from where my mother settled in the West in 1948” he “had **come to** numerous Marxist publications and had already read with great interest works by MARX, ENGELS, PLEKHANOV, Georg LUKÁCS, and Ernst BLOCH, which had been published 
there”.

Comment: As I can understand "come to" is short form of describing of moving from state A to state B. Before (A) he was without numerous M. publications, after (B) he already with them. What strange for me is choice "had come" instead "had came" but this is real language practice as I know. Here link to conversation about: https://www.writingforums.org/threads/had-came-vs-had-come.34154/

Answer (score 1):

It means found or discovered. I would have preferred 'come across' in this context.